# How can I debug a failing spring boot actuator health indicator while spring security is on the classpath?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-boot-actuator

I am trying to see which health indicators get auto configured in spring boot actuator.  i'm using spring boot 2.2.6, when I run my application locally and I navigate to /actuator/health I see "Status":"up".  when I deploy my application on a openshift cluster however the status always shows down so i'm guessing one of the auto configured health indicators are failing.  I use a custom JWT security implementation and it would be impossible to configure the Openshift readiness and liveness probes to use my security implementation.  I tried all suggestions I could find on Stackoverflow to set the actuator health endpoint to show all details including setting management.endpoint.show-details to always, management.endpoints.sensitive to "*" or false, management.security.enabled to false etc etc.  Nothing seems to work and i'm running out of ideas...  i'm thinking that I manually need to start disabling all health checks and then re-enable them one by one to debug this?  Any help/suggestions would be much appreciated, my latest management section of my application config file is below...

```
my config:

management:
  security:
    enabled: false

    #defaults:
    #enabled: false
    #consul:
      #enabled: false
    endpoint:
      health:
        show-details: always
        show-components: always
      solr:
        enabled: false
  endpoints:
    health:
      sensitive: "*"
    web:
    exposure:
      include: "*"
```

Comment: set "endpoints.health.sensitive" to "false" NOT "management.endpoints.health.sensitive". It should help you to debug. Also "management.endpoint.health.show-details" to "always" in your setup there is a security level between management and endpoint.

Comment: Thanks that did it!!! please add this as the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set

> endpoints.health.sensitive : false

NOT "management.endpoints.health.sensitive".

It should help you to debug. Also

> management.endpoint.health.show-details: always

in your setup there is a security level between management and endpoint.